# Как получить имя истинного роутера при включенных ЧПУ?

Tags: opencart

OpenCart 2.0.1.1 Стоит модуль сео который делает чпу ссылки. Мне нужно получить роут - где прописано какой контроллер, действие используется. get['route'] не определяется. подскажите как это сделать*?